# API controller keeps returning JSON after content type is changed to something different

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm writing an API controller and am attempting to have it return a jpg file. However even though the content type is set to "application/jpg", my response message is continuing to return a json.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {

        var path = @"C:\Temp\Sample\background.jpg";

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/jpg");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "application/jpg";
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "background.jpg"
        };
        stream.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

After calling the controller this is what it returns:

```
{
    "version": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "build": -1,
        "revision": -1,
        "majorRevision": -1,
        "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "content": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "Key": "Content-Type",
                "Value": [
                    "application/jpg"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Key": "Content-Disposition",
                "Value": [
                    "attachment; filename=background.jpg"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "reasonPhrase": "OK",
    "headers": [],
    "trailingHeaders": [],
    "requestMessage": null,
    "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calls are made to a web API the responses will always be in JSON (Thats just how HttpResponseMessages work). If you want to send an image via your API the two easiest methods are to either send a link to the image (if the image is hosted), or to first convert the image into a byte array like so:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{

    var path = @"C:\Temp\Sample\background.jpg";

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    using(var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)){        
        var image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
    }

    return result;
}
```

And then on your client side you can use something like this:

```
        var x = await client.GetAsync("Image");

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(x.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result))
        {
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response .So I took your advice and switched up my code to include the ByteArray implementation you were talking about. Is the return json supposed to contain a byte array?  The json I am getting there is no reffrence to any ByteArray and the content length is set to -1. The json looks exactly exactly the same except the content type is now  "image/jpeg".

Comment: Sorry, wrote this without testing it in my API first. Move "result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");" to be the last line of the using(){} block, it threw an error because the content hadn't been set yet. I've updated my answer to reflect the change

Comment: Yeah, I caught that on my end when I was testing. The problem is still there however. I have no content in my json, just headers.

Comment: Hmm, just tested on my end using a fresh web api + console app, image is being sent properly (you can also test by accessing that Get() request from the browser, it should show the image). Is the image definitely accessible by your api?